# VB .NET way to duplicate PHP + CURL curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/the/path/to/the/file.pem');

Tags: php, vb.net, curl

Using PHP, I send a .PEM certificate to a remote host with an outgoing request like this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/path/to/file.pem');
```

Is there a way to do this using VB .NET?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [X509Certificate2 Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx)...load the certificate object then use the

> ToString(True)

To get a verbose result...then transport that however you wish (including via SSL)...[HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) if the remote machine is open to accept http...[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) is a stackoverflow question on that.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I don't want the certificate sent in the actual HTTP request body, that's not how the CURL option works.

Comment: Well...ummm...this might be your solution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx